# How to access an enum in master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Can we access an enum which has been defined in the master page. I read about the master page on my own blog.

Comment: Sorry for being short handed ! I want to access a property that is enum and is declared in master page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean an actual `enum`, defining it elsewhere is a better option, but the same casting below works to get at it as well.

If you want to access the property that is an `enum` then cast the `Master` property of your page to your master page's type. Like this:

```
protected void override OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  ((MyMasterPagesType)Master).MyEnumProperty = MyEnum.Value;
}
```

Edit:

Almost forgot, you can also have the `Master` property on your page already behave as this  type by using the [@MasterType directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274.aspx) in your aspx markup.

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/masters/SourcePage.master”" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for noting the MasterType directive. Learn something every day on here :)

Comment: I don't believe this is entirely correct. The right hand side of the assignment should be: MyMasterPagesType.MyEnum.Whatever