# Referencing enum by shorthand from .Master file

Tags: c#, enums, master-pages

We have a structure roughly as below:

```
namespace a.b.c.d.e {
    Master file
    namespace f {
        Page file
        Enum Colours
        Enum Fruits
    }
}
```

The master file is made up of 3 files: .Master, .Master.cs & .Master.designer.cs.

Several functions within Page refer to Colours or Fruits. Within the .Master.cs file I have `using a.b.c.d.e.f` - this should mean that I can reference Colours & Fruits without fully referencing them. This works as expected in the .Master.cs file - however putting `<%=Page.GetTitle(Colours.Red)%>` in the .Master file does not work. It just says "The name 'Colours' does not exist in the current context". Instead I have to put `<%=Page.GetTitle(a.b.c.d.e.f.Colours.Red)%>`.

Where am I going wrong? If `Colours.Red` works fine in the .Master.cs file, surely it should work in the .Master file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access an enum in master page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117289/how-to-access-an-enum-in-master-page)

Comment: No. I have an enum defined in namespace f which I want to reference, without the full path, within the .Master file in namespace e. I can reference it fine in the code behind but not the markup file.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266357/declaring-an-enum-outside-a-namespace-in-a-project) you can move the enum outside the namespace so you don't have to reference it in your code. Otherwise, you need to keep using the full qualified name of the enum.